# how do I schedule pr checks rerun via github actions or other tools?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Currently I have a github action that gets triggered by pull_request. I need it to run nightly though, I can add the cron job trigger but then if it's triggered by schedule(cron job), there will be no github context from the pull_request and I need that context for later steps. Anyone knows how to achieve this? What I have just doesn't work-

```
on: 
  pull_request:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * * '
```

Comment: An option could be to save the `Github Context` from the **pull_request event** as an artifact, and then download it on the job that will trigger through the cron event. It would be similar to something explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161639/github-actions-post-comment-to-pr-workflow-that-triggered-the-current-workflow/68165696#68165696).